# jQuery toggle with drupal behaviors not really, well, behaving

Tags: jquery, drupal, drupal-7, drupal-theming

Well, I'm embarrassed to have to ask, but someone (probably many of you) know better than I do here: why am I having trouble?

Here's the trouble - this works fine if I start with the divs showing - but if I hide them, it doesn't toggle.  I see some "movement" on the page, but the divs don't appear.  This applies if I hide them via a jQuery hide() or toggle() in the first Drupal.behavior below, or if I remove that, and I hide them via css (i.e. display: none).  However, if I start with them unhidden, the toggle onclick works like a charm.  I'd just rather the user that the option to *show* them if interested, rather than *hide* them if not.

Ideas? (D7, btw, if not clear from the code below...)

```
(function($) {
    Drupal.behaviors.hideElements = {
      attach:function(context, settings) {
        $('.comparison-chart-category-elements-element').each(function() {
          $(this).toggle();
        });
      }
    };
    Drupal.behaviors.toggleElements = {
      attach:function(context, settings) {
        $('.elements-div-header').each(function() { 
          $(this).unbind("click").click(function() {
              $(this).html($(this).html() == "View Elements ∇" ? "Hide Elements &Delta;" : "View Elements &nabla;");
              $(this).next().slideToggle();
          });
        });
      }
    };
})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 0):

Alright.

Yes, that code above works fine.  If I had realized the next sibling in my DOM was of class `comparison-chart-category-elements`, rather than `comparison-chart-category-elements-element` I wouldn't have wasted your time.

Thanks for looking.